# cuda-gdb set breakpoint at another line of __global__ function

Tags: cuda, gdb

### Problem

I have a `__global__` function in CUDA and I want to debug it using `cuda-gdb` but I cannot set a breakpoint inside the kernel and it points to another line. Here is my code

```cpp
// include stuff
// ...
#define blockNUM 1
#define threadNUM 1
// ...
int main() {
    // ... (define d_R_0, d_R_1, d_R_2, and d_H)
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(threadNUM);
    dim3 numBlocks(blockNUM);
    decode<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(d_R_0, d_R_1, d_R_2, d_H);
    // ... (other codes go here)
}

__global__ void decode(uint *d_R_0, uint *d_R_1, uint *d_R_2, uint *d_H) {
    uint idx = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x); // --> I want to set breakpoint here! (line 197) <--
    // ... (implementation of the function)
} // --> But the cuda-gdb set the breakpoint here! (line 288) <--
```

And here is the cuda-gdb

```
(cuda-gdb) break 197
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa7f6: file /home/matin/main.cu, line 288.
```

### Extra Info

I compile `main.cu` using this command:

```
$ nvcc -g -G main.cu
```

I also have the same problem with the *A First CUDA C Program* snippet on [Nvidia's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/)

---

Specs:

- GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
- NVIDIA (R) CUDA Debugger: 11.5 release
- CUDA Version: 12.0
- Ubuntu Version: 22.04

Comment: I don’t see how this is answerable — you either have found a bug in the toolchain, or (more likely) the line of C++ code you are interested in doesn’t actually result in an instruction being emitted which the debugger can stop on. But you haven’t shown any concrete code someone could compile, disassemble and analyse or try and run themselves. Either way there is no answer to provide to your post in its current form

Comment: Even in Nvidia's __First CUDA C Program__ example that provided a complete code snippet, I can't put a breakpoint in the `y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];` line inside the kernel. @talonmies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my Nvidia drivers, I've encountered the same issue. I hope that this solution works for you too.

You have to **set the breakpoint using the kernel function name**. For example for the [First CUDA C Program](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/) you should follow these steps:

1. Set a breakpoint using the kernel function name

```bash
(cuda-gdb) b saxpy
Breakpoint 1 at 0x338: file /home/nahid/temp/saxpy.cu, line 5.
```

2. Run to reach the breakpoint.

```bash
(cuda-gdb) r
```

3. Finally, set the breakpoint to the line that you want!

```bash
(cuda-gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 2 at 0xfffe3258e10: file saxpy.cu, line 7
```